# C++ code coverage with Bazel 6 and lcov fails

Tags: code-coverage, bazel, lcov

I recently switched from Bazel 5 to Bazel 6. The following commands generated in the past a working code coverage report for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/Vertexwahn/FlatlandRT.git
cd FlatlandRT/devertexwahn
bazel coverage --config=gcc11 --instrumentation_filter="[:]" --instrument_test_targets=true --combined_report=lcov -- //...
output_path=$(bazel info output_path)
genhtml "$output_path"/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat -o coverage_report
```

In Bazel 6 the following error is reported:

```
genhtml: ERROR: cannot read /home/vertexwahn/dev/FlatlandRT/devertexwahn/external/Imath/src/Imath/ImathMatrixAlgo.h
```

Any ideas/hints on how to get a proper code coverage report with Bazel 6?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question. But is more a handy tip. The coverage report should also be available from the symlinked path `bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat`

Comment: You can try [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2528#issuecomment-414721024)

Comment: @SG_Bazel `Unrecognized option: --experimental_java_coverage` and I guess this is only Java related - want to find out code coverage of a C++ project. Also `coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/LcovMerger/java/com/google/devtools/lcovmerger:Main` does not work in Bazel 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I remove `--instrumentation_filter="[:]"` everything seems to work with Bazel 6.0. With Bazel 5.4.0 I do not need remove this flag.